# Resourcemodel plugin not working - Magento2

Tags: magento2, resource-model, after-plugin

**app/code/Mymodule/Orderedproductsreport/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection">
   <plugin disabled="false" name="Mymodule_Module_Plugin_ProductSoldCollection" sortOrder="2" type="Mymodule\Orderedproductsreport\Plugin\ProductSoldCollection"/>
</type>
```

**app/code/Mymodule/Orderedproductsreport/Plugin/ProductSoldCollection.php**

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\Orderedproductsreport\Plugin;
class ProductSoldCollection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
{

    public function afterAddOrderedQty(
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection $subject,
        $result,$from = '', $to = ''
    ) {


        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/ProductSoldCollection.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

        return $this;
    }


}
```

`public function afterAddOrderedQty` isn't working.

Can any one help me what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace is wrong
try this.

```
<?php
namespace Mymodule\Orderedproductsreport\Plugin;
class ProductSoldCollection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
{

    public function afterAddOrderedQty(
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection $subject,
        $result,$from = '', $to = ''
    ) {


        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/ProductSoldCollection.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

        return $this;
    }


}
```

**UPDATE**

use this class name.

```
class ProductSoldCollection extends \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection
```

and fire following command.

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

Comment: still not working and not showing any errors

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to extend any class in your Plugin, Please try below code

```
<?php

namespace Mymodule\Orderedproductsreport\Plugin;

class ProductSoldCollection
{

    public function afterAddOrderedQty(
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Sold\Collection $subject,
        $result,$from = '', $to = ''
    ) {


        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/ProductSoldCollection.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Your text message');

        return $subject;
    }


}
```

I verify this thing in My Magento with this URL **`base_url/admin/reports/report_product/sold/`** and that is working in my case.

Hope this will help!